# How to Allow Users to Upload Images to My Website?

Tags: html, jsp

I am doing a project in which I allow users to upload pictures. and allow other users to view them..
how can I do so,??
I am doing the project in Javascript,Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

You can try a premade script suite like EZ Scripting http://www.ezscripting.com/csv/.

The free one I don't think allows for file upload, but the pay version does. I use them on about 10 website projects. Stores the data in a flatfile and puts the files anywhere you want on your server. runs on perl, but super simple to use.